# General Bihomogeneous Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Notation. (Affine/Projective/Biprojective) Variety here means closed irreducible subset of (Affine/Projective/Biprojective) space (resp.). $S:= S(\mathbb{P}^m\times \mathbb{P}^n):=k[x_0,...,x_m,y_0,...,y_n]$ is a bigraded ring (it is graded over $\mathbb{N}^2$ that is), a biform is a polynomial $f=\sum F_i\in S$, together with $(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ s.t. each $F_i$ has the form $a_ix_0^{i_0}...x_m^{i_m}y_0^{j_0}...y_n^{j_n}$ and $\sum i_l=a$, $\sum j_l = b$. An ideal generated by biforms is called bihomogeneous.

> For sets $E\subset \mathbb{P}^m\times \mathbb{P}^n$, we let $I(E)$ be the ideal generated by the biforms vanishing at every point of $E$, for a set $A\subset S$ of biforms, we let $Z(A)$ be the points on biprojective space $\mathbb{P}^m\times \mathbb{P}^n$ which vanish at every element of $A$, and for a bihomogeneous ideal $I\subset S$, let $Z(I)$ be the set of points which vanish at every element of a generating set of $I$ consisting of biforms (write $I_{\mathbb{P}^m\times \mathbb{P}^n}(-)$ and $Z_{\mathbb{P}^{m}\times \mathbb{P}^n}(-)$ instead if there is danger of confusion)

For some time I was trying to form and prove a "bihomogenous version" of the Hilbert Nullstellensatz. Namely, something along the lines of the following.

> Question. Let $I\subset S$ be a bihomogeneous ideal. Then need we have $I(Z(I)) = \sqrt{I}$? If not, then perhaps (per a comment in a question I link below) $I(Z(I)) = (\sqrt{I}:(x_0,...,x_m))+(\sqrt{I}:(y_0,...,y_n))$. (see addition below)

I thought that I had proven (the former part of) this by just adapting the proof of the homogeneous nullstellensatz (as in, the "$I(Z(I)) = \sqrt{I}$" statement for homogeneous ideals $I$ of $k[x_0,...,x_n] := S(\mathbb{P}^n)$), but that (former part) I think is false, and I am somewhat suspicious of the latter part because I can't seem to find a statement like this anywhere (where "like this" means of the form "let $I\subset S$ be a bihomogeneous ideal, then $I(Z(I))=$ [some simple operation applied to I]).

Taking theorem 2.11 from [Bihomogeneous Nullstellensatz](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2650300/677593) for granted, 2.11 is still only in 4 variables, so it seems to be worth some investigation if this really is not true in (one of) the general form(s) that I stated in the question above.

> Addition. by the counterexample given in the above linked question, I think the "$I(Z(I)) = \sqrt{I}$" part of my above question is false, so hopefully the second part of my question is true at least.